# Android SDK in Eclipse gives error about expired certificate

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.1

When building Android project in Eclipse, Android SDK gives error like this:

error:

```
 Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
1) Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 7/9/11 6:31 PM     MapByLocation        Unknown Android Packaging Problem



 2)Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 7/9/11 6:31 PM  PageCurlAnimation       Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

I do not know how to solve. please help me.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To fix this problem, simply delete the `debug.keystore file.`

The default storage location for AVDs is

- In `~/.android/` on OS X and Linux.
- In `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\` on Windows XP
- In `C:\Users\<user>\.android\` on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

[Also see this link, which can be helpful.](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use the keytool utility to create a new debug keystore. The keystore that you are using has expired and that is the reason why you see the project shows up in eclipse with errors.

check this out http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/keytool/

Also before doing that delete the existing debug keystore from the location in Windows or Linux based on the OS you are using.

Comment: goood tutorial, but I have stoped on step Sign your application. where I need to run sh file. I think I dont have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1. go to folder `C:\Users\(your pc name)\.android\`
2. delete `debug.keystore` file and then clean and run

Answer (score 0):

For Windows XP go to
`C:\Documents and Settings\%userprofile%\.android` and delete `debug.keystore`, restart Eclipse and now your project will build without the error.

Example path:
`C:\Documents and Settings\raja.ap\.android\`
For other Windows versions, find your user folder and then delete the file.